# XMLHttpRequest working only at first call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an issue on an XMLHttpRequest object. Mainly, my code is supposed to check at every click on a "refresh" button if there are any records in a 
SQL table respecting some rules, and update them. My code looks somekind of:

```
//index.php

//Refresh button
<input type = 'button' value = 'Refresh' onmouseup="refreshFunction(document.getElementById('hiddenID').value);">

//Somewere in page
<?php
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' value = '$id' id = 'hiddenID'>";    
?>

//XMLHttpRequest function declared in the same page, at the bottom
function refreshFunction(a) 
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","queryPage.php?id="+a,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);      
}

//Now the query page queryPage.php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnOne IS NULL AND owner = '$id' AND columnTwo IS NULL");
  while($message = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
  {
    $idFound = $message['nrcrt'];
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE myTable SET columnTwo = '1' WHERE nrcrt = '$idFound'");
    echo "New record found<hr>";
  }
```

Now, what exactly is happening? When I first click on "Refresh" button, the query findes the records (let's say there are three), is updateting
them and is showing three messages:

```
New record found
New record found
New record found
```

At the second click, myTable is already updated with columnTwo set to '1' but the results are the same. Again those three messages are appearing 
and at every click someDiv gets other three messages, even that there are no more records to respect the query. Now, if I modify one value from 
columnTwo, the query dosen't seem to find it and keeps adding the three initial messages found at the first click. Untill I restart my browser 
(IE 11), no matter how I modify myTable, the results are same at those from the first click. It seems that the xmlhttp object is not being 
destroyed and with every click on Refresh button, xmlhttp is the same as the first time.

Comment: Are you sure that you are really calling server and not just obtaining desired data from the cache?

Comment: Yes, I thought at that but I don't really know how to test it. But if I'm thinking again, I deleted all my history, modified myTable and still same results.

Comment: Maybe you should include the code for `refreshFunction`.